# Excel Macro to Sum by Font Colour

Tags: excel, user-defined-functions, vba

I'm trying to write a macro in Excel to sum by font colour. A colleague has suggested I use this article for help: [ExtendOffice](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1418-excel-count-sum-by-font-color.html). 
 However, it always gives a syntax error, and I'm not sure why.

**The code is:**

```
Public Function SumByColor(pRange1 As Range, pRange2 As Range) As Double

    Application.Volatile
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim xTotal As Double

    xTotal = 0
    For Each rng In pRange1
        If rng.Font.Color = pRange2.Font.Color Then
            xTotal = xTotal + rng.Value
        End If
    Next
    SumByColor = xTotal

End Function
```

Comment: this code works nicely for me, how do you use it ? do you call it from a `Sub` ? or from a cell in a worksheet (as a **UDF**) ?

Comment: Just bear in mind the inherent flaw in using colour as data - changing the font colour will not trigger a recalculation so you have no guarantee that this function will actually be correct at any given time unless you force a recalculation.

Answer (score 1):

The only reason you might get an error, is if one of the cells inside `pRange1` has a `String` or some other non-numeric value.
You can modify your code by adding `If IsNumeric(rng.Value) Then`.

**Modifed Code**

```
Public Function SumByColor(pRange1 As Range, pRange2 As Range) As Double

Application.Volatile
Dim rng As Range
Dim xTotal As Double

xTotal = 0
For Each rng In pRange1
    If rng.Font.Color = pRange2.Font.Color Then
        If IsNumeric(rng.Value) Then ' <-- the only thing which might give you an error, if you have a String inside one of the cells
            xTotal = xTotal + rng.Value
        End If
    End If
Next rng
SumByColor = xTotal

End Function
```

How it is being called from a sheet's cell:

[image]

**Note**: if you change the font's color of one of the cells, you will need to refresh the value in the cell by pressing `{Enter}` on the cell with the formula again.

Answer (score 0):

This works good for me. Maybe you simply called it in the wrong manner.

For example, if I have data on the "D" column with some fonts in it, this code would work for me:

```
Public Function SumByColor(pRange1 As Range, pRange2 As Range) As Double
    Application.Volatile
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim xTotal As Double
    xTotal = 0
    For Each rng In pRange1
        If rng.Font.Color = pRange2.Font.Color Then
            xTotal = xTotal + rng.Value
        End If
    Next
    SumByColor = xTotal
    MsgBox (SumByColor)
End Function

Sub count_colors()
    Call SumByColor(Range("D2", "D" & ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count), Range("D2"))
End Sub
```

(I ignored D1 since it's a header for me. You can change to anything you like)

I do have to agree with Rory, however, that using fonts as data separators is not a good idea